# Redirect to a razor page without current route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a page, which expects some route values like this:

```
@page "{reportYear:int:range(2000, 2100)?}/{reportMonth:int:range(1, 12)?}"
```

A model looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync([FromRoute]int? reportYear, [FromRoute]int? reportMonth)
{
    if (reportYear.HasValue == reportMonth.HasValue) 
    {
        MyViewModel.ReportYear = reportYear ?? DefaultReportYear;
        MyViewModel.ReportMonth = reportMonth ?? DefaultReportMonth;
        return Page();
    }

    return RedirectToPage(PageName);
}
```

The idea is that if both route values specified and are correct, show the page with them.
If both of them are not specified, still show a page but with default values.

And if only one of them is specified, redirect to the same page, but without any route values, to show a default version and use a clear address.

The problem is that "RedirectToPage" redirects with route values retained.
In other words, if i visit to "/pageName/2018" i get a redirect to the same "/pageName/2018"
The supplied route value (2018) is not getting stripped from redirect.

How do i clear the values and redirect just to a page?

P.S.
Url.Page(PageName) also returnes "/pageName/2018" in this case. Route values are not getting removed.

P.P.S.
I just want to make a user experience a bit better.
If a user typed an incorrect page address (i.e. "/pageName/2018"), i want to remove that incorrect part (2018) from address and a show a default page, like simple "/pageName".

P.P.P.S.
I know i could fiddle around with JS stuff that works with an address bar, but don't like that approach.

Comment: Hm, you should be able to explicitly clear the values by providing them: `RedirectToPage(PageName, new { reportYear: null, reportMonth: null })`

Comment: A bit unintuitive, but worked! Could you add your comment as a answer, so i could mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When redirecting to the same page or action, the link generation takes the ambient values, that is the route values for the current route, into account when generating the target URL. I’ve [asked about this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3746), and apparently this is primarily done to allow the usage of `Url.Action()` or `Url.Page()` to link back to the exact same page, similarly to how relative URLs work in HTML.

However, you can always overwrite the ambient values by explicitly specifying the route values in the `RedirectToPage` call:

```
return RedirectToPage("Test", new
{
    reportYear = (int?)null,
    reportMonth = (int?)null,
});
```

This will explicitly set the route values to `null` and overwrite whatever values still exist as ambient values.